# How to write file with VBA utf-8 problem?

Tags: excel, vba, utf-8

I want to parse a dictionary into a JSON with this logic:
https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON
and write it to a file.

Parsing works, writing the file as well, but characters like öäü are displayed wrong.
Here is my code:

```
Function writeJsonFromDict(dict As Dictionary)
    Dim fsT As Object
    Set fsT = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    fsT.Type = 2
    fsT.Charset = "utf-8"
    fsT.Open
    fsT.WriteText ConvertToJson(dict, Whitespace:=2)
    fsT.SaveToFile "path/to/file.json", 2
End Function
```

Expected output:

```
  "myValue": "Bühne",
```

Actual output:

```
  "myValue": "B\u00FChne",
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am afraid that you **previously should STORE/LOAD UTF-8 strings in the used Dictionary**. Otherwise, **it converts the dictionary characters AS THEY'VE BEEN LOADED**... How did you load the dictionary? If you try reading a key/item containing such characters, how do they look? But **NOT** in Immediate Window. There, they will look strange. Try writing in an Excel cell... Does it return `"Bühne"` in that cell? And another question: **Where did it return in the way you show**? In Immediate Window? If so, try returning in a cell. You maybe have a correct string but you test it wrongly...

Comment: BTW, result of `ChrW(252)` is `ü`  and `00FC` is the hex value of 252.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!

The writing is ok. 
But ConvertToJson(dict, Whitespace:=2) can't handle "äöü...". 
Wrote a quick string replace logic for all chars I need to handle. 
Obviously there are better ways but this was the fastest for me.

```
Function replaceUTF8Chars(content As String)
    content = Replace(content, "\u00E4", "ä")
    content = Replace(content, "\u00C4", "Ä")
    content = Replace(content, "\u00F6", "ö")
    content = Replace(content, "\u00D6", "Ö")
    content = Replace(content, "\u00FC", "ü")
    content = Replace(content, "\u00DC", "Ü")
    content = Replace(content, "\u00DF", "ß")
    content = Replace(content, "\u00E8", "è")
    content = Replace(content, "\u00E9", "é")
    content = Replace(content, "\u00A0", "ê")
    replaceUTF8Chars = content
End Function
```